# Search from hadoop hdfs data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am extracting data from an online source in JSON form, and storing it into Hdfs through Apache Flume. Now it creates multiples files as Hadoop does. Now i want to search something from this data (from all these files) and get complete info related to it. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can develop your own script to search in hdfs with MapReduce or Spark . You have another solution , you can use hive and or Pig . 
Pigg guide : http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/pig/tutorial.html 
hive guide :  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual